# Select N symmetrical edges in a sphere

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, edges, select

If I'd like to select two symmetrical vertical edges in a sphere it is easy to do that manually:
[image]

Four would be easy too:

[image]

But with other divisions it could be harder to do so manually.
Is there a simple way to select n edges that are covering the sphere with equal distance between each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Switch to edit mode, edge select.  Select an edge *ring* (ctrl alt click on edge for me):

[image]

2. Use a "checker deselect" operation.  Choose a number of selected+deselected that goes evenly into the number of divisions.  The number of times this goes into your divisions will be the number of edges that remain selected.  Set the offset equal to the number deselected:

[image]

3. Use "select/select loops/edge loops" operation:

[image]

With 48 divisions, select 1 deselect 3, I have 12 loops selected, although you might see it as 6 loops, since they are continuous across the UV sphere's poles.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to talk about our lord and savior **Geometry Nodes**?

Go to *Geometry Nodes* workspace:

[image]

Change it to **Tool Mode** and give it a name `Select Symmetric`:

[image]

Create this simple node setup:

[image]

You can do so by first pressing the <kbd>N</kbd> key to open the right panel and then add a group input there:

[image]

then you can drag from this socket to an empty space, and type the name of the node you see on the screenshot:

[image]

Repeat for all other nodes - make sure all values, connections, and options are the same:

[image]

Finally, in Edit Mode, press <kbd>F3</kbd> and search for your tool `Select Symmetric`. Then click in the bottom left corner to expand the settings or press <kbd>F9</kbd> to open the popup. Adjust the settings (for this setup/geometry not all numbers will be valid):

[image]

Happy noding!

Comment: Thank you! Ahh.. you have a leaflet for me! Great! I shall read it with interest. If you don't mind, at the moment, though, I'm a bit busy.

Answer (score 3):

A variation on [@Nathan's method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/310690/35559):

- Select one edge, then another, at the desired interval.
- Press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> ('Select Next Active') to
  accumulate selections at the same interval.
- Then, as in his method, use Header > Select > Select Loops > Select
  Edge Loops.